# Windows 2008 server Task Scheduler giving error 0XC0000005

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, console-application, windows-server-2008, taskscheduler

I have published a console application through .Net Core2, and copied the output folder with EXE file on server.

If I double click and execute it is running all fine. But when I am scheduling it though task scheduler it is giving error - 0XC0000005

Any idea what needs to be fixed, or how to troubleshoot this more.

I did try to recreate it from the Administrator account too, but same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the - Start In value did the job for me.

Comment: Thanks that helped me. I had tried everything else, but when I ran across this I thought why not, nothing else works. Quite weird.

Comment: Dang, took me a while to realize I didn't copy the path, in fact I was duplicating an existing process pointing at a different configuration and I forgot the path. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It appears that .Net Core console app needs to run with the optional path so it can find the appsettings.json if you are using one.

[Schedule a .Net Core console application on windows using Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595119/schedule-a-net-core-console-application-on-windows-using-task-scheduler)

[image: Edit Action]