# MassTransit Consumer - .NET 6.0 Console Application - Deployment Options

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, masstransit

I'm relatively new to MassTransit and have been following the tutorials on the MassTransit website, which are all working as expected, but I have some questions regarding deployment.

Tutorials: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/consumers.html#consumer

I'm wondering at the most basic level how someone creating a MassTransit Consumer in a .NET 6.0 Console Application would deploy this console application on a Windows Server and ensure that it's always up and running to consume messages? Say for example the server was rebooted, etc...

Short of creating a Docker container, what other options exist? Run a WorkerService as a Windows Service?

Comment: Windows Service is one option. Also, Windows Task Scheduler is another option.

Comment: [Straight from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) on how to host .NET 6 in a Window Service.

Comment: As Adam said, running inside the windows task scheduler is also a good idea. For how to run your application inside the windows task scheduler, I suggest you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60457227/7609093).